# onClick attribute striped out in rendered html

Tags: theming, javascript

I have below code in my Form. But after rendering i could not see the onClick attribute in the link.

```
$form['step2_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Next'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="left"><a onClick="javascript:back_callback(1);" href="javascript:void(0)" class="back_btn">'.t('Back').'</a></div><div class="right">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#name' => 'step2',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('enabled-for-ajax')),
    '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => '::myajaxmethod',
              )
);
```

But i got the below output, without `onClick` attribute and `javascript:` in the output.

```
<div class="left"><a class="back_btn" href="void(0)">Back</a></div>
```

Is this restricted? If so, how to achieve this in drupal 8?

Comment: I added id in a tag and used that in javascript to complete my task. But still i want to know what could be the right way to do this.

Comment: The right way would be to attach a js library to the form, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```php
$form['cancel'] = [
  '#markup' => '<div class="left"><a onClick="javascript:back_callback(1);" href="javascript:void(0)" class="back_btn">' . t('Back') . '</a></div>',
];
$form['step2_submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Next'),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="right">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#name' => 'step2',
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['enabled-for-ajax']],
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::myajaxmethod',
  ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks. But, still my question is, placing a link (a tag) in '#prefix' with onclick attribute is not the right way of implementation?

Comment: @siddiq Yes, It is not a right way to implement any link.